# how to kill many process in sql-server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i can see open process like this:

```
select spid from master..sysprocesses where db_name(dbid)='MyDB'
```

and i can kill procces like this: `kill 54`

but how i can kill more then one process ?

i need to kill all the open process that my select... query return to me

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

On a busy site connections can pop up again as soon as you kill them. Do you need this?

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

/*Do your task here*/

ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET multi_user
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to kill them all, consider using a cursor to loop over each row of of your result(s).  You can probably wrap it up in a SP to make easy to use.

Comment: Here is a post where they did something similar using a cursor to kill connections: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/01/sql-server-cursor-to-kill-all-process-in-database/

Answer (score 0):

I typically use dynamic SQL for things like this.  Much better than killing 50 processes one at a time, but obviously you want to exercise caution with what you include in the `WHERE` clause and be sure you're only killing the processes you intend to, there's no undo button.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT (
                    'KILL '
                    , p.spid
                    ), CHAR(10))
        FROM sys.sysprocesses p
        WHERE p.hostname = 'whatever'
        )

exec(@Sql)
```